# How do you reverse a string character by character in java?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a string with the phrase "Bank of America". I want to reverse it so the output results in "aciremA fo knaB"

This is the code I have been trying to use but the output is only the last letter of the last word, which would be "a"

```
int position = phraseLength;
for(int index = position-1; index >= 0; index--);
System.out.println(p1.charAt(position-1));
```

I am not sure what is wrong here so any help would be appericated.

Comment: What is that `;` after the `for` loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Debugging is a critical skill for all programmers. I strongly suggest that you learn how to use your IDEs built-in debugger. You can also add more System.out.println() statements to your code in order to see what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added an extra semicolon after for loop here

```
for(int index = position-1; index >= 0; index--);
                                                ^
```

Also you are always accessing the `postion-i`. You should access the `index`

```
System.out.println(p1.charAt(position-1));
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                here
```

You can use this

```
int position = phraseLength;
for(int index = position-1; index >= 0; index--)
    System.out.print(p1.charAt(index));
```

or this

```
String output = "";
int position = phraseLength;
for(int index = position-1; index >= 0; index--)
    output+=p1.charAt(index);
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Also `index` must be used. `p1.charAt(index)`

Comment: That helped a lot. It is now reversed by character but now I have another problem. System.out.println prints every letter on a new line while System.out.print prints it together but on the same line as another output.

Comment: @Ryan Then put a system.out.println() with no parameters before the loop.

Comment: take other string object and append the characters to it !!

Comment: @hexafraction It added an empty output line and didn't solve my problem. Thank you anyways.

Comment: you can also use `System.out.print` in place of `println` to avoid the new line and then print a newline character at the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("Bank of America");
    System.out.println(sb.reverse());
```

If you want to do it your way. use

```
    int position = phraseLength;
    for(int index = position-1; index >= 0; index--)
        System.out.println(p1.charAt(index));
```

Comment: yup another way if he wants to use built in method .. +1

Comment: It's better to use a `StringBuilder` here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by mistake you have added the `semicolon` after for loop. Practically this will not give any `compile time error`. But the content of the loop will be executed only once. So remove the semicolon and get it done !!

Comment: He also should use `index`.

Comment: The loop executes the same number of times with or without the semicolon it's just with the semicolon the loop is empty (except for the decrement and comparison) so nothing visibly happens. The line that will only execute once is the `println`

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverse(String str) {   
 char [] buffer = str.toCharArray();

 for (int i = 0, j = buffer.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
  char temp = buffer[i];
  buffer[i] = buffer[j];
  buffer[j] = temp;
 }

 return new String(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer("Bank of America");
System.out.println(stringBuffer.reverse());
```

Comment: It's better to use a `StringBuilder` here.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string.
Take out the length of that string.
Loop through the characters of the string.
Add the characters in reverse order in the new string.
String str = "hello";

String reverse = "";

int length = str.length();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

```
 reverse = str.charAt(i) + reverse;
```

}

System.out.println(reverse);